# Self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A, B ∈ \mathcal{B}(H)$ be selfadjoint operators on a Hilbert space and assume that $0 ≤ A ≤ B$.
Prove that $\|A\| ≤ \|B\|$.

I tried to show the claim by using the fact that if $A$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$, then
$\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|$ (and the same for $B$). And as we know that $0 ≤ A ≤ B$, it follows that $\|Ax\|≤ \|Bx\|$. So, $\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\| ≤ \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Bx\| = \|B\|$. But I think that it is not okay.

Comment: The step $||Ax|| \leq ||Bx||$ is not justified (it would require $A^2 \leq B^2$, which does not follow from your assumptions). You should use (or try to prove) that, for a symmetric operator $A$, $||A|| = \sup_{||x||=1} |\langle x, Ax \rangle$|.

Comment: So if I prove that ||A||=sup|⟨x,Ax⟩ |, then I could use that |⟨x,Ax⟩ |≤|⟨x,Bx⟩ | ?

Comment: Yes, $|\langle x, Ax\rangle| \leq |\langle x, B x\rangle|$ follows from $0\leq A\leq B$.

Comment: Thank you so much!